# JMeter - Allow different IP addresses for each HTTP request element in a thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan that has an HTTP request defaults element that I have used to specify the IP address to be used by each HTTP request element in a thread group. Each HTTP request element does not have an IP address specified because it is inheriting the IP address from the HTTP request defaults element.

The above setup works perfectly, but I can't add an HTTP request element that has the IP address field specified where said IP address is different from the IP address specified in the HTTP request defaults element.

In other words, I'm trying to create a test plan with HTTP requests elements using different IP addresses, is this possible?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Group elements by their destination to different sections using simple controllers.

[image]